# Dynamically Generate Questions in Google Forms Without Creating New Columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a Google Form where a question is dynamically generated by a script.

The form is designed to capture the results of product inspections, which can either result in a pass or a fail. The inspections are raised as the result of a product issue, and continue on for a certain period of time until the issue is resolved - at which point they are closed.

I currently have the form set up as a web app, which will generate a multiple choice grid item upon opening based on the inspections that are currently required.

The form pulls in all of the currently active inspections from the linked spreadsheet, and generates the question options based on this data. However, the script is creating a new set of columns every time the form is opened, even if many of them are the same inspection.

Is there a way to only generate a new column if the question added is new? And if the question is not new, can the responses for this question be funneled into the original column on the spreadsheet?

Thanks.

```
function doGet(){
    
  var form = FormApp.openById("###");
  
  var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");
  
  var sheet = workBook.getSheetByName("###");
  
  var range = "A:B";
  
  var options2DArr = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var options = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options2DArr.length; i++) 
        {
              if (options2DArr[i][0] != "")
              {
                options.push(options2DArr[i][1] + " (" + options2DArr[i][0] + ")");
              }
    
  }
  
  myCheckBoxItem = form.getItemById("###").asGridItem();
  currentRows = myCheckBoxItem.getRows();
  myCheckBoxItem.setTitle('Inspection Results')
  .setRows(options)
  .setColumns(['Pass', 'Fail']);
  
  var URL = form.getPublishedUrl();
  // redirect to the prefilled form URL dynamically created above 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + URL + "\"</script>");

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean that once somebody answered a question in the form - the response shall be synched with the workBook, and the form shall be updated in such a ways that it does not include the already answered questions anymore? In which column of the spreadsheet do you want to set the result (Pass or Fail)?

Comment: The Pass/Fail result should be stored under the column based on the question. So for example, the result of the first inspection should be stored under the 'Inspection 1' column. Inspection 1 may be used for a period of weeks before being retired. The issue is that every time the form is updated with the list of inspections (for example because Inspection 2 has been introduced), another 'Inspection 1' column is created and all future Inspection 1 results go into that column rather than the original. Therefore you end up with 20+ 'Inspection 1' columns, but I want them to go in the same one.

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot of what it currently looks like and what you would like it to look like - that owuld be very helpful for udnerstanding!

Comment: Are you using a Google Form or a web app?

Comment: It's a web app script leading to a Google Form. I will post a screenshot tomorrow when I'm at work. Thanks for replying.